# php e() and h() functions?

Tags: php, cakephp

I and lately I'm seeing `h()` and `e()` functions in PHP. I have googled them, but they are so short that results don't give any idea of what they are. I got results like exponential or math related functions. For example:

```
<td><?php echo h($room['Room']['message']) ?></td>
```

Does anyone have an idea? or maybe they are not called functions? (I think I read about that very long ago, but I can remember its real name)

#### ADDED:

Thanks, for the replies. I am using CakePHP and also found an `e()` example:

```
<?php e($time->niceShort($question['Question'] ['created'])) ?>
```

If they were escaping somehow strings I think it would make sense, since I always see them right next the "echo"

I still don't know what they are ;(

Comment: Thanks to all, I thought it was php and it was cakephp in fact! 

h(string $text, string $charset = null)
Convenience wrapper for htmlspecialchars().

e(mixed $data)
Convenience wrapper for echo().

Comment: A convenience wrapper for echo? Odd.

Comment: @Noufal - 1 total vote as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like it might be CakePHP.

See [e()](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Global-Constants-and-Functions.html#e)

> e (mixed $data)
>
> Convenience wrapper for echo().
>
> This has been Deprecated and will be removed in 2.0 version. Use
>   echo() instead.

See [h()](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Global-Constants-and-Functions.html#h)

> h (string $text, string $charset = null)
>
> Convenience wrapper for htmlspecialchars().

Comment: thanks, for this... It is a big help, and I am getting closer ;)

Comment: Without any prior knowledge about CakePHP, I have put an identical h() in my PHP util code, too. Also s() for mysql_real_escape_string().

Answer (score 29):

As several readers have said, these are CakePHP-specific short-cuts. You can find them in the API docs at: [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html) (for CakePHP 2.x)

I think I read that some of these are going to be removed in 1.3, personally I never used e() as typing echo really doesn't take that much longer :)

edit: e() is deprecated in 1.3 and no longer available in 2.0 [see here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Global-Constants-and-Functions.html#e)

Comment: +1 for providing an actual link, unlike all the other answers that either say what the functions *aren't* a member of, or surmise that they're CakePHP without committing to that as the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Most likely, they are dummy functions someone introduced for the sake of brevity. The h(), for example, looks like an alias for htmlspecialchars():

```
function h($s)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($s);
}
```

So look for them in the include files. Espec. the ones with names likes "util.php" or "lib.php".

Answer (score 8):

They are probably functions defined and implemented by the group's code that you're looking at. I'm not aware of any e/h functions in the PHP language.

Nothing here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.h.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.e.php

Answer (score 8):

Likely the framework you're using is doing some escaping and has defined some short hands for `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` or equivalents.

I'd do a search on whatever framework you're using for "function h("

Answer (score 6):

There aren't any functions in PHP called h() and e(). They must be declared in the project you are working on. search for them and find out what they do.

Answer (score 5):

In CakePHP h() is:
 Convenience wrapper for htmlspecialchars()

For more information about Global constants and functions in CakePHP view this link

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess that `h()` escapes user-submitted data for safe output, and `e()` escapes for database insertion. Whatever the functionality, these are not stock PHP functions.

Comment: `e()` may also be `urlencode`. Personally I use `h()` to do `echo(htmlspecialchars())` to cut down on templating verbosity.

Answer (score 3):

It's CakePHP.

```
echo h('some stuff')
```

Is just `htmlspecialchar()`ing the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a decent editor press ctrl and click on the function. It should take you to the function's declaration.

Comment: These would have to be actual stock PHP functions for that to work.

Comment: Not really. I know in Netbeans you can go to the declaration so long as the file where it is declared is in your include path. It's a good way to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel also use `e()` helper function to runs **htmlentities** over the given string.

```
echo e('<html>foo</html>');

// &lt;html&gt;foo&lt;/html&gt;
```

documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-e

Answer (score 1):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/121/Global-Functions these are shortcut functions in cakePHP

Many of them are deprecated in 1.3 so beware of using them yourself

Answer (score 1):

**`h()`** is global function in CakePHP. Documents about **`h()`** for CakePHP version 2.5.7 : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#global-functions